# Evaluating the limit of the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^{2n\pi}\frac{(n+x)\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x)^2}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I am stuck on this integral

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{2n\pi}\frac{(n+x)\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x)^2}\,dx$$

I have learned MCT and DCT, but I don't how they might be applicable. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: *Hint.* Split the integrand into two parts: $$\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{x(1+x)^2}+\frac{\sin(x/n)}{(1+x)^2}.$$ Then by using the inequalities $\left|\sin x\right|\leq\left|x\right|$ and $\left|\sin x\right|\leq1$, show that each of the integrand is dominated by an integrable function.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\color{red}{\large\text{Just for your curiosity}}$

$$I_n=\int_0^{2n\pi}\frac{(n+x)\sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x(1+x)^2}\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{n (t+1) \sin (t)}{t (n t+1)^2}\,dt$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{n (t+1)}{t (n t+1)^2}=\frac{n}{t}-\frac{n(n-1)}{(n t+1)^2}-\frac{n^2}{n t+1}$$ Each of the antiderivatives can be computed in terms of the [sine and cosine integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) (do not worry if you do not know about them : it will be soon). So, we know the definite integral wich write
$$I_n=n \text{Si}(2 \pi )+$$ $$\frac{n-1}n \left(\left(\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\text{Ci}\left(2 \pi
   +\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\text{Si}\left(2
   \pi +\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)-$$
$$n \left(\left(\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\text{Ci}\left(2 \pi
   +\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\text{Si}\left(2 \pi
   +\frac{1}{n}\right)-\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$

Expanded as a series for large values of $n$
$$I_n=1+\frac {\log(n)-\alpha}n +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ where
$$\alpha=\gamma +\frac{1}{4 \pi }+\frac 12\text{Si}(2 \pi )-\text{Ci}(2 \pi )=1.38843\cdots$$

For example, for $n=100$ this very truncated expression gives $1.03217$ while the "exact" value is $1.03250$.